# Validating String in C#

Tags: c#

Hi so im trying to validate my string here so that it does not allow any input that starts with: "911" so if you type: "9 11", "91 1", "9 1 1" it should go through my if statement. It works with "911" but not the others, here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Phone_List
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var phoneList = new List<string>();
            string input;
            Console.WriteLine("Input: ");

            while ((input = Console.ReadLine()) != "")
            {
                phoneList.Add(input);

                for (int i = 0; i < phoneList.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (phoneList[i].Substring(0, 3) == "911")
                    {
                        input.StartsWith("9 11");
                        input.StartsWith("9 1 1");
                        input.StartsWith("91 1");
                        Console.WriteLine("NO");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        return;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("YES");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to use "`input.StartsWith("9 11")`;" but it does not work...

Comment: That code doesn't really make much sense, you are writing the `StartsWith` checks inside the condition block when it already started with "911" and nothing else. Also, you have to check if `StartsWith` returns `true`, right now, your checks do nothing.

Comment: google "Regular Expression". They are constructs designed to validate strings with rules like this.

Comment: Employ regular expression.Here Regex for all strings starting with 911 would be "911.*" . When there is a match you know the current input starts with 911

Comment: You can try to remove the space before validating by using input.Replace(' ', '');

Comment: Step through the code and you'll see at least one of the problems. (Another problem is that you are calling `StartsWith` and throwing away the result.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expressions for checks like this.

For example:

```
Regex.IsMatch(input, "^\\s*9\\s*1\\s*1");
```

This regex matches all strings that include whitespaces in front of and between "911".

Comment: I get a: "unrecognize escape sequence" by writing this code.

Comment: @Cleon Sorry, forgot to escape the backslash. Normally escape sequences are written like this `\s`, but `\ ` is a special character in strings, so you have to escape it. This results in `\\s`. The updated answer is now correct

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of `String`; the condition you describe can be formulated as follows.

```
input.Replace(" ", "").StartsWith("911")
```

Comment: So I tried writing this code before my if statement and it still does not work, am I missing somthing?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to check if the string starts with `"911"`:

First create a copy from the input string but without any white spaces:

```
string input_without_white_spaces =
    new string(input.ToCharArray().Where(x => !char.IsWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray());
```

Then you can check if the string starts with 911 like this:

```
if (input_without_white_spaces.StartsWith("911"))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool valid = s.StartsWith("911") || 
            !string.Join("",s.Split()).StartsWith("911");
```